# Azure Key Vault Secrets Spring Boot Starter 0.1.5

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-keyvault

I am using older version of Azure Key Vault Secrets Spring Boot Starter -- 0.1.5
Also older version of spring-boot-starter as shown below::

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.15.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

There were no code changes for Azure keyvault, In application.properties we added below:

```
azure.keyvault.uri=<<Keyvault URL>>
azure.client-id=<<Keyvault client Id>>
azure.client-key=<<Keyvault Key>>
```

Now I upgraded the versions of Spring boot starter and azure keyvault as below::

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

### application.properties

```
azure.keyvault.uri=<<Keyvault URL>>
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
azure.client-id=<<Client-ID>>
azure.client-key=<<Cleint key>>
```

Its failing with below Errors, Can you please help what i need to do if i am upgrading to latest version.

13:36:59.270 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to configure KeyVault property source
at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessorHelper.addKeyVaultPropertySource(KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessorHelper.java:110)
at com.microsoft.azure.keyvault.spring.KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(KeyVaultEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:47)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:200)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:188)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
at com.honeywell.CaaS.GatewayManagerAPI.webapi.SpringBootMain.main(SpringBootMain.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Max retries 3 times exceeded. Error Details: Network is unreachable: connect
at com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy.lambda$attemptAsync$1(RetryPolicy.java:119)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:185)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:251)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:251)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:251)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:545)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:545)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:196)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:134)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:171)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2346)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:143)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:182)
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:162)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:156)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:432)
at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:518)
at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:561)
at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:448)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:594)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:425)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1526)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1287)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1324)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.lambda$checkIMDSAvailable$14(IdentityClient.java:463)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:91)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:126)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you miss the property `azure.keyvault.tenant-id` in the application.properties.

I have reproduced this error **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to configure KeyVault property source**. See:

[image]

After adding `azure.keyvault.tenant-id=<your-tenant-id>` in the file. It works:

[image]

---

I refer to [How to use the Spring Boot Starter for Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault) and the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/release/2.3.2/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-sample#azure-key-vault-secrets-spring-boot-starter-sample). To let it work, make sure the application has permissions to get and list secrets in access policies of your key vault.

**application.properties**

```
azure.keyvault.enabled=true
azure.keyvault.uri=https://{your-azure-keyvault}.vault.azure.net/
azure.keyvault.client-id=put-your-azure-client-id-here
azure.keyvault.client-key=put-your-azure-client-key-here
azure.keyvault.tenant-id=put-your-azure-tenant-id-here
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <azure.version>2.3.3</azure.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**DemoKeyVaultApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoKeyVaultApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

   @Value("${test1}")
   private String testSecretName;

   
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoKeyVaultApplication.class, args);
    }

    public void run(final String... varl) throws Exception {        
        System.out.println("testSecretName stored in Azure Key Vault: " + testSecretName);
    }
}
```